# ellipsizeMode={'head'} did not work when numberOfLines > 1 in React-Native

Tags: javascript, text, react-native

I am trying to show ... in the starting of the text but it is working when `numberOfLines={1}`

**Code:**

```
<Text style={styles.equationOrResultStyle} numberOfLines={1} ellipsizeMode={'head'}>
                {this.state.equation}
            </Text>
```

[image]

But nothing happing when i am using `numberOfLines={2}`

**Code:**

```
<Text style={styles.equationOrResultStyle} numberOfLines={2} ellipsizeMode={'head'}>
                {this.state.equation}
            </Text>
```

[image]

But same is working for `ellipsizeMode={'tail'}`

**Code:**

```
  <Text style={styles.equationOrResultStyle} numberOfLines={2} ellipsizeMode={'tail'}>
                    {this.state.equation}
                </Text>
```

[image]

where equationOrResultStyle is:

```
equationOrResultStyle: {
    fontSize: 10,
    textAlign: 'right',
    color:'#ffffff',
  },
```

Why `ellipsizeMode={'head'}` not working when `numberOfLines` is  more than 1 ?

Is there any workaround for the same?

Comment: What is the style for `equationOrResultStyle `?

Comment: @PritishVaidya check the updated question

Comment: Seems like a weird issue, on ios it adds `...` to the start of the second line and doesn't work for android

Comment: @PritishVaidya yes i was testing it on android

Comment: did you find the solution yet ? @AjeetChoudhary